# Book Identification about a giant spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship

I read a comedic science fiction novel as a kid, sometime in the early 1970's, in which a man is alone on an enormous (thousands of miles, as I recall) abandoned spaceship. It was very funny (and I realize it sounds a lot like the premise of Red Dwarf, but this was decades earlier). I can't remember much more, and haven't been able to find any clues as to the title. I did wonder if it might be "Venus on the Half-Shell" by Philip Jose Farmer/Kilgore Trout, so I bought a copy of that and skimmed through it, but I'm pretty sure that wasn't it after all.

Comment: What was funny about it?

Comment: I honestly can't remember anything specific - other than laughing out loud as I read it (I must've been about 12 years old).

Comment: Was it the novel based on the early computer game "Starship Titanic" both by Douglas Adams?

Comment: Nope, the book I read was much older (I read it in the early 1970's), but thanks for that guess - I hadn't heard of "Starship Titanic" and I enjoyed reading its Wilkipedia entry.

Answer (score 6):

Update: I finally figured it out. It's *[Bernhard the Conqueror](https://vintage45.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/bernhard-the-conqueror-sam-j-lundwall-1973/)* by Sam Lundwall (DAW books, 1973).

[image: Berhard the Conqueror book cover]

> Bernhard Rordin, Private E-1 in the Armed Forces of the Galactic Empire is serving a twenty year sentence on a prison planet nicknamed Ol’ Slow Death. One day the massive ship Refanut passes overhead. It’s hard to miss since it’s twenty thousand miles long.
>
> A scoutship lands next to Bernhard. The man is looking for the Pleasure Palaces. He doesn’t know how much time has gone by and that they don’t exist anymore. When he dies Bernhard manages to get into his scoutship and get to the Refanut.
>
> Now he runs into all kinds of bizarre adventures including coming across a door that’s in love with him that ends up putting him into a trash compactor. Also on board is Captain Superhawk and over six hundred officers.
>
> They’re happy to see Bernhard because he’s the only Private they’ve seen and they divide up the time each has to abuse him. He eventually escapes to the Comet.  Not much better there.

Comment: Once you merge your accounts as per the instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts, you can accept your answer.

Comment: Wow, the cover picture doesn't seem to have much to do with the plot.  For that matter, your plot synopsis here doesn't match the question very well — I thought you said he was alone.  (But, yes, this sounds like it could have been at least part of the inspiration for _Red Dwarf_.)